# Reporting template is missing in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

Reporting template got missed in visual studio 2017, I installed crystal report still version 13_0_18, Existing reports are working
while running but i cant able edit that reports, How do install
Reporting template in visual studio 2017. when am trying to open any
.rpt file it is showing like binary form, Its not opening in Crystal
report editing window.